# Problema entre sistema C# e plugin Warsaw (GAS Tecnologia)

Tags: c#, java, applet

Meu projeto foi construído com a linguagem C#. Tudo estava ocorrendo tranquilamente, até alguns clientes começarem a relatar erros ao abrir meu sistema. O erro acorre da seguinte maneira: o cliente clica no atalho na área de trabalho e o sistema abre (normalmente, como padrão) e tudo mais. Só que alguns clientes instalaram o plugin de segurança de um banco que é baseado em JAVA. O que acontece é que quando executa esse plugin no computador, ou seja, ao entrar no site do banco e fazer o login, o meu sistema não executa mais de forma correta... Depois de executado esse plugin, ao abrir meu sistema, todo o conteúdo do formulário desaparece, deixando o formulário todo em branco....

Alguém já passou por esse problema de incompatibilidade? Como que eu poderia resolver?

Já tentei de tudo. Já restaurei o computador a dias antes do ocorrido, mas mesmo assim depois de um tempo esse erro volta e não sei mais como resolvê-lo.

Será que alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Para não ficar muito extenso o espaço dos comentários; a conversa de foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110375/discussion-on-question-by-erik-thiago-problema-entre-sistema-c-e-plugin-warsaw)

Comment: Estou fechando como fora de escopo por se tratar de um defeito em aplicação precária de terceiros, que interfere de maneira irresponsável em sistemas alheios. A única solução neste caso é remover a aplicação ofensiva, que é o tal plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para resolver o problema de incompatibilidade, tive que entrar em contato com a GAS Tecnologia descrevendo o problema que estava ocorrendo.

Eles pediram uma série de informações, pediram que mandasse o meu projeto inclusive, o caminho onde ele ficava instalado no windows e tudo mais... Passaram também o link que o @Randrade me passou e nada de resolver o problema. Então depois de muito insistir, eles resolveram o problema. Não explicaram o que fizeram, mas pelo que entendi, o Warsaw é bastante intrusivo no SO, agindo também em outras aplicações e não somente no navegador, que é o seu propósito.

Entendi também que eles "liberam" aplicações pelo caminho dos arquivos onde se encontram no "Arquivos de Programas" ou outro lugar onde a sua aplicação mantem os arquivos necessários a inicialização.

Ou seja, para resolver, é necessário que se entre em contato com eles por email, porque eles não passam telefone para suporte, descrevendo o problema e mantendo contato, pois eles podem findar o problema, mas não avisam ao interessado.

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 4):

Finalmente resolvi meu problema com esse plugin!

Passei alguns meses com este problema, sem detectar que a causa era o plugin, com formulários ficando brancos, sistema ficando lento e até paralisando totalmente o Windows, chegando a ponto de ter que reiniciar todo o sistema.

Até que um dia consegui visualizar o carregamento dele na tela de Output, rodando a aplicação em modo Debug. Então abri a janela dos Módulos carregados no Visual Studio (Menu Debug->Windows->Modules), e confirmei o carregamento do tal plugin. Vejam a Figura abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Ao observar que se tratava do carregamento de um processo não gerenciado, apenas desabilitei a opção do projeto que permitia debugar esses códigos (Propriedades do Projeto -> Debug ->Enable Unmanaged Code Debugging).**

Tenho vários projetos em C, c++ e Fortran na minha solução que requerem esta opção para debugar, mas agora só vou ativar ela enquanto precisar.

**Após desativar essa opção o plugin não foi mais carregado e toda a aplicação ficou mais rápida!**

Acho que vale a pena comentar também que enquanto este plugin estava sendo carregado, ocorreram alguns loops demorados em códigos não gerenciados,  inclusive aqueles que usamos talvez sem perceber, como o OpenFileDialog e SaveFileDialog, que carregam internamente API's do Win32.

Espero que esse seja o problema de todos ou que ajude alguém a encontrar outros pontos de carregamento desse plugin!

Comment: Em resumo, se um programa se comporta mal, como o referido plugin, a única solução viável é remover o plugin. Absurdo seria se sujeitar a dar satisfaçao para uma empresa dessas sobre uma aplicação que não é da conta deles.

Answer (score -1):

Passei por um problema similar e parece que os meios de solução de problemas com a GAS tecnologia não estão mais disponíveis.

Atualmente a solução é através do formulário de contato da Diebold (que deve ter adquirido a GAS Tecnologia/GAS Antifraud):

https://www.dieboldnixdorf.com.br/contato-antifraude

Escolhendo "empresa", nesse formulário é possível fazer um pedido de white list da aplicação, fornecendo informações como o path de instalação/URL ou mesmo o aplicativo via link.